Two kinds of treatment with multiple ways administered?
I am creating a research proposal as an undergrad student. I want to look at the impact of two different kinds of messaging on behaviour. However, each message will be administered by different methods. For example: one message is about encouraging girls to go to school, the other is encouraging students to go to school listing the benefits of schooling. I want this to be administered in 4 different ways: either only to the mother, only to the father, to the mother and father separately, to the mother and father together. If want school registration of girls to be my dependent variable, what kind of regression do I create? I'm fairly confused.
Should it be:
girlregistrations = constant + interaction:mother_only*girl_message + father_only*girl_message + motherfather_separate*girl_message + motherfather_together*girl_message + error
Where each term is an interaction between dummies: mother_only will be 1 if the treatment if administered to mother only. Girl_message will be 1 if the message administered is the one that encourages girl schooling instead of the gender neutral benefits message.
Am I missing something?
Any input would be really really appreciated.
Thank you so much.
Edit: the experimental unit is a family with 2 parents + a girl child (of age in line with school registration age), with outcome of registrations measured at the individual level. (treatment is administered through door to door canvassing in certain villages with only 1 school. control is other villages with only 1 school but no treatment administered). For villages assigned to the treatment group 1 (girl message) or treatment group 2 (generic message), homes are randomly assigned to the 4 different ways of treatment administration.
girlregistrations is defined by whether girls in that family have registered to send the child to school by the forthcoming deadline

I'm not sure it's clear what the experimental unit and the outcome are? For example: is the experimental unit a two-parent family with a school-aged girl? Or all the families that send their children to the same school? Similarly for girlregistrations: how exactly is it defined?

I have made some edits!

Thanks for the edit. Your experiment has a complex design, so it's great that you are planning for the analysis in advance. To summarize: The outcome Y is binary. There is one treatment, T1, which takes one of three values (No message, Girl message, Generic message) and another treatment, T2, which takes one of four values (mother only, father only, both together, both separately).

The T2 is nested in the T1 because the "No message" families aren't contacted in any way. See this thread How do you deal with "nested" variables in a regression model? for more on how to deal with this. Also -- have you considered running simulations to get more understanding on how the data might look like under reasonable assumptions about "effect sizes" and how to do the analysis?
